# Plotting the world map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize some data from countries in a world map using R and `ggplot2`. I am using the following code(sample):

```
WorldData <- map_data('world')
df <-data.frame(region=c('Hungary','Lithuania','Argentina'),value=c(4,10,11))
Total <- merge(WorldData,df,by='region')
```

and for plotting using ggplot:

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon(data=Total, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group,fill=Total$value),colour="white") + 
         scale_fill_continuous(low = "thistle2", high = "darkred", guide="colorbar")
P1 <- p + theme_bw()  + labs(fill = "legend" ,title = "Title", x="", y="")
P1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c()) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c()) + theme(panel.border =  element_blank())
```

The output is this:

[image]

I believe that the problem is in the `merge` because when I change the data option in `geom_polygon` to `WorldData` and the `fill` option to `1` I have the following result:
[image]

Is this happening because I do not have data from all the countries in `df`? How can I overtake that?

edit: What I would like is to plot the whole map. (I was not clear in my description)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also work in "layers" as other GIS environments let you (which will also let you not merge the data). This can be achieved in many ways, but I like to use `geom_map`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

WorldData <- map_data('world') %>% filter(region != "Antarctica") %>% fortify

df <- data.frame(region=c('Hungary','Lithuania','Argentina'), 
                 value=c(4,10,11), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

p <- ggplot() +
    geom_map(data = WorldData, map = WorldData,
                  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, map_id=region),
                  fill = "white", colour = "#7f7f7f", size=0.5) + 
    geom_map(data = df, map=WorldData,
                  aes(fill=value, map_id=region),
                  colour="#7f7f7f", size=0.5) +
    coord_map("rectangular", lat0=0, xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-60, 90)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(low="thistle2", high="darkred", guide="colorbar") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c()) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c()) +
    labs(fill="legend", title="Title", x="", y="") +
    theme_bw()
p
```

[image]

That also has a projection (via `coord_map`) so you'll get consistent output and gets rid of Antarctica.

Comment: Wonderful!, I was triying to produce this all day long, just one question, my map have missing information for some country, I would like them to show as gray or something, how can I do that?.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the ordering of the points in each polygon. The points in `WorldData` need to be drawn in order (which is partly represented by the `order` column, and `merge` does not preserve this order. You can fix this by adding the line:

```
Total <- Total[order(Total$order), ]
```

before your plot, which sorts the `Total` data frame so that the `order` column is ascending.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `merge()` sorts the data before the merging happens, but to plot a polygon correctly, you need to preserve the order of the original map data.

Rather than a merge, try to construct your data frame like this:

```
Total <- WorldData[WorldData$region %in% df$region, ]
Total$value <- df$value[match(Total$region, df$region)]
```

---

The full code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

WorldData <- map_data('world')
head(WorldData, 100)
df <-data.frame(region=c('Hungary','Lithuania','Argentina'),value=c(4,10,11))

Total <- WorldData[WorldData$region %in% df$region, ]
Total$value <- df$value[match(Total$region, df$region)]

ggplot(Total, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill = value)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "thistle2", 
                        high = "darkred", 
                        guide="colorbar") +
  theme_bw()  + 
  labs(fill = "legend" ,title = "Title", x="", y="") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c()) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c()) + 
  theme(panel.border =  element_blank())
```

[image]