# Error : don't know how to add ggplot to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a map with points of differents colors for each actor
which commit violence.

Thanks you for your help :)

```
library("readxl", lib.loc = "C:\Users\Student\Downloads\sll-ledsierre-   leonelocalsource1991-2001.xlsx")
library("ggplot2")
library("ggmap")

qmap("Sierraleone" , zoom = 8)

df <- read_xlsx("sll-ledsierre-leonelocalsource1991-2001.xlsx")

map <- qmap("Sierraleone" , zoom = 8)
#only violence against civilians

df1<- df

install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
install.packages("magrittr")
library(magrittr)

df1 <- filter(df1, df1$EVENT_TYPE == "Violence against civilians")

map + ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE)) +
geom_point(alpha = 0,5, size = 1) +
aes(colour=ACTOR1)
```

an example of my dataset `(head(df))` with only the interesting columns for my map

```
ACTOR1     LATITUDE     LONGITUDE

1 RUF: Revolutionary United Front     8.11     -11.6
2 RUF: Revolutionary United Front     8.11     -11.6
3 RUF: Revolutionary United Front     7.96     -11.7
4 RUF: Revolutionary United Front     7.96     -11.7
5 RUF: Revolutionary United Front     7.96     -11.7
6 RUF: Revolutionary United Front     7.96     -11.7
```

I get this error message

Error: Don't know how to add `ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE))` to a plot

Comment: `qmap()` calls `ggplot` internally, so you can't use `ggplot()` again in building the same object. Put `data = df1, aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE)` inside `geom_point()` and delete the `ggplot()`.

Comment: Thanks you ! I tried but.. 

> map + geom_point(data = df1, aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE), alpha = 0,5, size = 1) + aes(colour=ACTOR1)

Error: `stat` must be either a string or a Stat object, not a numeric vector

Comment: That is because you have `alpha = 0,5` when you should have `alpha = 0.5`. R thinks you are using separate arguments, `alpha = 0` and `stat = 5` (because `stat` is the next argument)

Comment: Thank you, it's better step by step... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with maps on R, but maybe you could check here ([Plotting the world map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706124/plotting-the-world-map-in-r)) and put longitude and latitude in `geom_map()` and not in `ggplot()` like that :

```
ggplot() +
    geom_map(data = df1, map = map, aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE))
```