# how to get draw world map in R?

Tags: r, geospatial

My objective is to plot is to plot raster file(.tif) into a world map. When I draw world map using terra like this -

```
terra::plot(rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf"))
```

[image: world map sf]

However, I want world map like this -

```
terra::plot(rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sp"))
```

[image: world map - sp]

I am aware of ggplot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706124/plotting-the-world-map-in-r) . But I would like to use a terra plot so that I add new raster on the existing plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using only the geometry attributes achieve what you are looking for?

```
terra::plot(rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")["geometry"])
```

Comment: Perfect! Now wondering if results from `geometry` can be converted using `spatRaster` to be used in `terra` functions.